# Is cron job time based or is it server timezone based?

Tags: time, cron, jobs, zone

I have a cron job that is set to run at midnight. I would like to know if this is midnight from the server timezone or is it as soon as i create the cron job i have to wait 24h until it's being executed?

Comment: If your crontab is set to run at midnight then it will run every midnight according to the servers clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to wait 24 hours. The cron in launched in the scheduled hour based on server's time.

Comment: What if I chose it to execute every 12 hour? Will it be 12 hours from midnight or how will the 12 hour execute work?

Comment: You have to tell the cron at what hours your want to execute (min, hour, day/month, month and day/week). If you say 0 0/12 * * * the task will be executed at 0:00 and 12:00.